# dpkg fail install 'code-oss'

Tags: raspberry-pi, dpkg, debian-installer

Hi I wanted to install Visual Studio Code on Raspberry Pi 3

After install vs code via dpkg I got error:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./.build/linux/deb/armhf/deb/code-oss_1.20.0-1516181563_armhf.deb
(Reading database... 135207 and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../code-oss_1.20.0-1516181563_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking code-oss (1.20.0-1516181563) over (1.20.0-1516181563) ...
Setting up code-oss (1.20.0-1516181563) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/code-oss doesn't exist
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-9)...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1)...
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the `.deb` package to a temporary directory with `ar x <package name.deb>`.

You'll get three files:

- `debian-binary`, a package version indicator
- `data.tar.gz`, the files installed by the package
- `control.tar.gz`, the pre/post install/remove and configuration scripts for the package.

Extract the `control.tar.gz`. Examine any postinstall and configure scripts, find the `update-alternatives` command(s) within them, see what is wrong with them. Use the knowledge you gained to fix your `code-oss` installation if possible. Send a bug report to the packager in any case.